# Put image on image background through php to form one complete image

Tags: php, image, facebook-graph-api, background-image, facebook-opengraph

I want to get user profile picture on an another background image i have used my facebook java sdk and api all those thing to get uid of the user and uid is also displayed but i m not getting image on another image i only want to display user dp on an image background i have tried all possible ways hope you get better one I want to display image which is in `$t3` variable with a background image which is created by `$jpg_image` and also want to know how to set location of the db.

```
    <?php 
    $text = $_GET['uid'];
    $t3 = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$text."/picture?width=200&height=200";
    $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('img/sunshine.jpg');

    imagejpeg($jpg_image);
    imagedestroy($jpg_image);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As i understand from your question - you actually need to compose new image from 2 given images, try to investigate about **php-gd**, **php-imagick** libraries (I personally would prefer php-imagick), these libraries can provide you with tools for image manipulations like you requested. enjoy..

Comment: Actually Now I only want to display and image which is online streaming from the url background image is working and also wants to know how to set location of the image which we get from the url